# Ask Questions, even if you already know the answer

Tags: discussion

Requesting all members to ask more questions, encourage people to ask questions, vote for questions, because the status on area51 shows dismal question asking rate ([8.1 questions per day, required is 15](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7551?phase=beta)), answer rate is above the required level.

I am already asking questions that I already have answers for, ask logical questions that chess enthusiasts may ask. We need to do this to generate more interest and making site go live.

**[Edit]**

It is 0.9 Questions per day, now we definitely need to start doing this.

Comment: Are you saying questions per a day is the only reason the site is not in public-beta now?

Comment: no, but I am trying to make sure this does not become a reason when that time comes.

Comment: **RELATED-QUESTION:** [how-and-when-does-the-public-beta-begin](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-and-when-does-the-public-beta-begin)

Comment: The stats *ought* to be abysmal when the site starts out, there are so few users.  The stats are for evaluating mature beta sites.  Faking the numbers is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Posting questions and answering them is in fact okay, but in my opinion is not sustainable long-term, and may lead to problems. Effort should be on asking real questions, and getting real answers.

My suggestion would be to focus on getting more users to the site, not posting content.

Comment: I agree, don't post just for the sake of posting.  If you are going to ask a question, try to ask a real question, possibly with some analysis. Those questions will drive people to the site in my opinion.

Comment: +1 @xaisoft: Yes, I agree, showing existing effort via research/analysis within the question itself is a huge part of asking good questions.